# I have created a sorting visualizer but it's not showing the animation it's sorting the array but no animation

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

```
const n = 10;
const array = [];

init();

function init() {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
    array[i] = Math.random();
  }
  showBars();
}

function play() {
  const copy = [...array];
  const swaps= selectionSort(array);
  showBars();
  animate(swaps);

}


function animate(swaps){
  if(swaps.length == 0){
    return;
    showBars(i,j);
  }
  const [i,j] = swaps.shift();
  [array[i],array[j]]= [array[j],array[i]];
  showBars(i,j);
  setTimeout(function(){
     animate(swaps);
   },50);
 }

function change(i,j) {
  var temp = array[j];
  array[j] = array[i];
  array[i] = temp;
  return array[i];
}

function selectionSort(array) {
  const swaps = [];
  do {
    var swapped = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var min = i;
      for (let j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j] < array[i]) {
          min = j;
          swaps.push([i,j]);
          //
          swapped = true;
          change(i,j);

          //array[i-1],array[i]=array[i],array[i-1];
        }
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
  return change;
return swaps;
}



function showBars() {
  container.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const bar = document.createElement("div");
    bar.style.height = array[i] * 100 + "%";
    bar.classList.add("bar");
    container.appendChild(bar);
  }
}
```

I was expecting an animation of elements getting sorted but didn't get to see.

Comment: What is in a container? Please post the HTML too.

Comment: <h1>Sorting Visualizer</h1>
<div id="container">

</div>
<hr>
<div class="">
  <button onclick="init()">init</button>
  <button onclick="play()">play</button>

</div>

<script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: A quick test in a .html gives me this in the browser console: Uncaught TypeError: swaps.shift is not a function or its return value is not iterable
Are you shure the .shift function exists on swaps?

Comment: i'm new to this i don't know much about it please fix this